# SAP UI5: Merge/join two tables

Tags: javascript, join, merge, sapui5

I am looking for a way to merge/join to tables in SAPUI5 (preferably with JavaScript).

For the first table, I upload data from an Excel sheet (using SheetJS) and the second table gets generated out of an `InfoObject`.

Now I want to take the data from the first table and add it to the second table, based on the technical keys of the `InfoObject` table. (Looking for a way to search for the matching technical keys and then replace the data accordingly)

How can I achieve something like this? (I am not asking for a complete solution, just for some input on how/where to start etc.)

Here's the code to upload an Excel sheet:

```
_import : function(file) {
        var oTable = this.getView().byId('uploadData');
        if(file && window.FileReader){
            ... code
    },
```

Comment: i am pretty shure it's not a good solution, thats why only as comment: apply formatters for the joined columns with the forign key as parameter and then select the columns data in the formatter, i hope someone can think of something better  : P

Comment: Hi by reading I can only suggest that you can use the same model for the two tables for binding and one is updated the other gets updated automatically. Doesn't mater on keys but items with diff properties.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot merge the data from the two separate sources into one model and bind that model to your table?

Comment: @CharalamposAnargyrou if I would simply merge, I would not consider the technical keys of the tables. I want to check if some new data got upload for e.g. key 1, if yes, that row gets overwritten, if not, nothing happens. and if the uploaded table contains a key that doesn't exist yet in the old table, it should be appended

Comment: This is not clear. It's hard to imagine that anyone could think that "take the data from the first table and add it to the second table, based on the technical keys of the InfoObject table" is clear. Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly say what you want. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It is probably best to merge and then bind to the model. Depending on the required browser support and your appetite for external libraries, you can use one of these approaches:

- Use `lodash` [`unionBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unionBy to merge the 2 arrays on the technical key. The new data should be in the first array.
- Convert the arrays to objects with the technical keys as keys, then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge them. The new data should be in the second object.
- If neither of the above are suitable, write your own algorithm. My guess is that starting with converting the arrays to objects would end up being the efficient option.

Comment: thanks for your answer! My tables are not two arrays, since one of them is an InfoObject, which gets imported by an OData Service, so I would have to convert this to a JSON which is probably not very efficient.. Do you have an idea how I would create a new InfoObject entry with a row of my uploadTable?

Comment: In some way,  the InfoObject ends up as an array as it is being bound to a table... So you need to follow the processing in generateTableView to determine the best way to merge.